# java compiler cannot find a class symbol

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compiler-errors, cannot-find-symbol

Im starting to use IntelliJ IDE for Java, when I try to compile my project the compiler says that it cant find a class A. The file A.java is located in src_gen folder. This is my project structure:

- Project/

  - src

    - B.java
    - ...
  - src_gen

    - A.java
    - ...

I have marked the src_gen folder as a soruce folder in intelliJ (it has the blue icon), and also the IDE recognizes the class (there is no red underline beneath the class name when Im using it in B class) and doesnt mark it as unknown identifier or anything. The problem occurs only when I try to compile the project.

Comment: Just because IDEA recognizes it does not mean the compiler will.  Are you using a Maven project?  If so, then any source code outside of the `src` folder may be getting ignored.

Comment: yeah I know thath but Ive read that if I mark a folder in IDE as a source fodler that the intelliJ automatically adds it to the java classpath.. so I guess it is not ture.. 
I have imported the project from git repository so I suppose it is using some default build script

Comment: Please provide a downloadable .zip of your complete project that can be loaded into Intellij IDEA.

Comment: oh, do you want to see only some specific files? because it is my bachelors work and I would like to not share it publicly :)